# Recovering a partition overwritten by a Microsoft Recovery Partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, windows-11

I'm trying to help a friend recover data from a partition that suddenly disappeared in Windows.

Before asking me for help, he tried to reassign a letter to the partition but this obviously created a Microsoft Recovery Partition in the process, which made the data on the partition disappear.

I tried to analyze the whole thing, test some data recovery software, but I have no idea if it is possible to recover data on a partition overwritten by this type of process.

Is it possible? Do you have any suggestions for effective software for this?

The situation is specific and I can't find an answer online because here we are dealing with a data loss following an overwriting by a Microsoft Recovery Partition. This makes the recovery process specific.

Thank you!

Comment: ask here: https://www.reddit.com/r/datarecovery/

Comment: This answer is actually specific: https://superuser.com/a/1758086/705502